# Facebook plugin for IOS and Android Game App

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to propose from what I understand of the flow of the client and server side of the mobile game to achieve facebook login and also using user facebook picture and username.

FLOW

1) Client side- User clicked on facebook login/signup function, client side will get access token from facebook, then we will use client side to pass the access token to our server and validate it with facebook to see if it is valid, then we store a valid session on our server.

2) As we authentiate whether if the user is valid,we also get and store url to their fb profile picture, and also full name to be used to display, as for the latest graph api we only get app scoped id, but not fb id, so i think it is compulsory to store picture link and full name to be displayed for other user which is not friend of theirs on fb.

So there are 2 parts to my question 1 and 2, please do comment if my flow is correct, especially of the 2, as I think that my proposal will take up a lot of the database and server will be slow.

And if we dont store it, i dont think we can retrieve user profile picture link and their name with app scoped id alone, as from what i understand, we will need access token to retrieve those, and even there is a solution by just using app id and app secret, that means that we will have to make a lot of queries and download a lot of queries from fb and redirect those data to user, but we will save spaces on database, and also get life update if the fb user changed those datas

Answer (score 0):

The second part of your question "displayed for other user which is not friend of theirs on fb" seems to be a violation of Facebook platform policy.

> 2. Only show data obtained from a user access token on the devices
>      associated with that token.
> 3. Only use friend data (including friends
>      list) in the person’s experience in your app.

Your app may not be approved in such a case.

You can work with user's friends instead. Once a user has granted you `user_friends` permission, you can make a call to `/me/friends` edge to get the friend's name and id.
In iOS (using the Facebook SDK 4.x) you can then get the profile picture of the person with the following code:

```
FBSDKProfilePictureView *profilePicture = [[FBSDKProfilePictureView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
[profilePicture setProfileID: friendId];
```